# I need to derivate the maximum likelihood of GLR function

Tags: neural-networks, derivative, function

I am trying to do the partial derivative of this function but I don't know how to include the $\theta$ inside my function to be able to apply the partial derivative in $\theta$.

The likelihood function is

$L(\theta)=P(X|\theta)=\prod_{i=1}^{m}\sigma (x_{i})^{y_{i}}(1-\sigma (x_{i}))^{y_{i}-1},$

and the log-likelihood function is

$\log(L(\theta))= 
\sum_{i=1}^{m}(y_{i}\log(\sigma (x_{i}))+(1-y_{i})\log(1-\sigma(x_{i}))).$

The gradient of the log-likelihood with respect to $\theta$ is

$\frac{\partial \log(L(\theta))}{\partial(\theta)} = ?$

I need to do the partial derivative of the maximum likelihood function, if you can help me how to start leaving the theta indicated for me to continue with the derivative $\theta$

Comment: Hi and Welcome to X Validated! Take a look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask. I edited your question. Please check if it is what you meant. Are you asking how to compute the gradient of the log-likelihood with respect to the parameters?  What is $\sigma(x_i)$? Please, clarify.

Comment: Because $\theta$ does not appear anywhere in the RHS of your log-likelihood, it's impossible to understand what you mean. I think the answer will be quite apparent if you re-write the RHS to include $\theta$ and apply the chain rule for differentiation. Also, between the likelihood and the log-likelihood, you've switched $1 - y$ and $y- 1$.